# Application extensibility in Concrete5 vs drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, content-management, concrete5

I am a novice for both concrete5 and drupal however I have been looking at Concrete5 and Drupal. I am looking to create a web application that needs to be extensible. Client requirement will start from basic content management and it will need to extend to workflow based web application. I have been looking at the architecture for Drupal and Concrete5. For those who haved used either one which one would you recommend? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My two cents... Concrete 5 is far superior to Drupal.

I have over 25 sites using C5 right now. I have had 4 drupal installs in the past and have converted all of them to C5.  I have also used Joomla, Expression Engine and PyroCMS extensively.

When I first started using C5, there were some great advantages for my customers in terms of end user updates to pages.  It is FAR more simple for an average non-tech user to update content.  This was a major win in my eyes.  Most users were struggling to update content with the other options because it wasn't fluid or as WYSIWYG.  The inline editing of C5 is outstanding.

That said, it was also very easy to convert HTML into templates using the tagging commands of C5.  So in no time at all, I could take a site that was static HTML or PHP and convert it into a C5 instance.  Again, very simple.

Within the last 6 months or so, I would say the extensibility has increased dramatically.  New modules are added to the marketplace nearly daily.  Some are FREE and some are paid, but I think ALL of them are cheap for the functionality and worth it.  Most are $20 in that range.

If you know PHP well, you can write your own modules easily and not have to pay a dime and also not worry about the C5 core upgrades.  There are lots of mechanisms built in that help developers take advantage of the system without having to worry about getting lost in software upgrades.  This was another great advantage, that has cost me in the past with other CMS platforms.

In summary... Concrete5 is a top-notch CMS that is widely extensible with a ton of functionality that is super easy for anyone to use.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using concrete5 for about 2 years now and I can wholeheartedly recommend it. Drupal is more powerful, but the amount of work that needs to be done to get to the starting point that c5 gives you right after install is huge. The concrete5 core provides you with a whole lot of stuff out of the box, and adding further functionality is straightforward with its comprehensive (although not always terribly well documented) API and active forums.

In terms of downloadable addons, there are many which cost but I've found that in many cases it's simpler to pay what is normally a low sum to get the functionality I need than to spend all the time (and time = money) coding it myself. Those situations where I've had to code a solution have been pretty painless - any trouble has been my failing, not the CMS'. Hooking into the core is really easy, including adding Dashboard pages for particular functionality (there's a helpful howto from Andrew, the core dev, on the site which explains how to do it).

Of course, the trump card is users' ability to edit their sites without having to understand UI 'metaphors' and 'paradigms'. It just works. You go to the page, click edit, and type away. Simples. My experience with pretty computer-illiterate clients has been very positive indeed, and I feel genuinely confident when I tell new prospects that they can expect to learn how to edit their site in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using C5 for over a year now.  The core team for C5 is committed to making it better and better every release, and they often implement contributed Code....but the thing I like most over say, Joomla, is that the directive of the CMS doesn't change.  while it is open source in that solid community contributions that line up with the overall vision will be included, the core team (original developers) oversee all aspects of the code.  So it's more carefully comed over than other "community driven" CMS's.

There is a huge community involvement and help in everything from getting started to deep programming.

And above all other things...Clients pick up using the C5 dashboard in minutes.  You'll be lucky to get that in most other CMS's.

Comment: Does that answers the question?! I thought the question was about module/product development in both CMSs (extensibility)!

Answer (score 1):

I have enough experience with to confidently say that it is pretty extensible. There are modules for most common things that you would want to do. If there isn't you can always create you own module. Downside is that the learning curve can be a bit overwhelming at first. Drupal's UI had been lacking but it's been improved with Drupal 7. But it also benefits from a decent sized community.

I also dabbled a bit in Concrete5 and was impressed with it's easy to use content editing functions. From what I remember, there was a smaller learning curve and the metaphor they used for content mimicked a normal static website with files and folders. The other big difference I noticed was that most of the modules have to be paid for. Not sure if that means they would be of higher quality but something else to consider.

I'm also interested in some perspectives from Concrete5 users.

Comment: Thanks for the input and +1. I have limited time to choose between the two CMS. It is either those two CMS or create my own from scratch. Through my dabble with Drupal 5 I am feeling the high steep learning curve. With concrete5 I like the ease of theming and ease of integration between modules. With Drupal it is a bit clunky and need a bit of development to get modules to integrate nicely. The one thing I like about Drupal is how you can create huge web application from it and also scale up well since a lot of enterprise drupal apps are in production.

Comment: If you're already tight on time I wouldn't recommend building a CMS from scratch unless you have very basic requirements. You don't want to waste your time rebuilding all the CMS subsystems like users, permissions, url routing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Concrete5 hands down is the best CMS I have used. I'll second what Chad says about clients picking up on C5 in no time at all.  When I demo Concrete5 to potential clients that first thing they usually say is "I can do that."  Users also love that amount of functionality that comes rigth out of the box and I like that fact that most of the code that I have worked with in my experience has been pretty solid.

Answer (score 1):

As CTO of concrete5 I'm a little bit biased, but I can tell you that concrete5 does offer a lot of extendability, and we try to do so in a way that scales the learning curve along with your knowledge of the system.

For example, the CMS tools are simple to understand right out of the gate. You can build sites with no customization that clients can easily edit. Then, when you need a bit more, you can go to our marketplace to download free or commercial add-ons that extend the functionality of your site. Once that isn't enough, it's easy to create custom block types which present small, encapsulated bits of presentational content on your site, and let your clients use the CMS to place new instances of them. If you need more than just bits of content, you can use concrete5's custom model-view-controller functionality to start working with full pages and external scripts. From there you can start diving into the framework itself, including our concept of events (similar to hooks in Drupal/Wordpress), helpers, attributes, and libraries, and start working with our file manager, user manager, permissions and interface at a low level. You don't *need* to know any of that stuff to get started, however, which is what we think makes concrete5 so compelling.

And, as Chad mentioned, when you get the stuck, the community is one of the best and most responsive out there.